# I need to create a procedure in oracle and have to implement below logic

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a master table with a column `Tel_num`. `Tel_num` is 11 digits data like *02365785431*. Now I have to take first 7 digits of the the tel_nums(substr( tel_nums,1,7)) and take the *min* as `start_num` and *max* as `end_num` when the numbers are in sequence.

If below things come up:`

```
023158100001
023158100002
023158100003
023158100004
023158115645
023158111546
023158111547
023158111617
023158121110
023158121111
```

Then I want the numbers like

```
Start_NUM                    End_NUM
023158100001                023158100004

023158115645                023158111547

023158111617                023158111617

023158121110                023158121111
```

This thing i need to implement . Can someone help??

Comment: What did you already try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hint : 1 `Cursor` Loop, 1 `If` condition and 1 Variable to store the `Start_NUM` is all you need :)  This isn't really very difficult to implement using plsql.

Answer (score 3):

No need for PL/SQL (as suggested in a comment). Keyword is *gaps and islands* (if you want to search for it).

I modified sample data (as they were wrong, according to desired result).

```
SQL> with test (tel) as
  2  (select '023158100001' from dual union all
  3   select '023158100002' from dual union all
  4   select '023158100003' from dual union all
  5   select '023158100004' from dual union all
  6   select '023158111545' from dual union all
  7   select '023158111546' from dual union all
  8   select '023158111547' from dual union all
  9   select '023158111617' from dual union all
 10   select '023158121110' from dual union all
 11   select '023158121111' from dual
 12  ),
 13  inter as
 14  (select tel,
 15          lag(tel) over (order by tel) lag_tel
 16   from test
 17  ),
 18  inter_2 as
 19  (select tel,
 20          sum(case when nvl(tel - lag_tel, 1) = 1 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by tel) tel_group
 21   from inter
 22  )
 23  select min(tel) min_tel,
 24         max(tel) max_tel
 25  from inter_2
 26  group by tel_group
 27  order by 1;

MIN_TEL      MAX_TEL
------------ ------------
023158100001 023158100004
023158111545 023158111547
023158111617 023158111617
023158121110 023158121111

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. It was the thing I was searching for . Plsql procedure was too tedious.A great help

Comment: can you tell me if another column i need to populate with that suppose line_value ...i mean min_tel , max_tel ,  line_value ...how to implement with this query.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to ignore the "first 7 digits" part of the question, because I don't think that is relevant.  I would just use the difference with row numbers to define the adjacency:

```
select min(tel_num), max(tel_num)
from (select mt.*,
             row_number() over (order by tel_num) as seqnum
      from master_table
     ) t
group by (cast(tel_num as decimal(11, 0)) - seqnum);
```

If you are concerned about sequences spanning the first 7 digits, then just include that in the `group by`:

```
select min(tel_num), max(tel_num)
from (select mt.*,
             row_number() over (order by tel_num) as seqnum
      from master_table
     ) t
group by substr(tel_num, 1, 7),
         (cast(tel_num as decimal(11, 0)) - seqnum);
```

Why does this work?  The difference between the number and a sequence is going to be constant when the number values increment by one.  So, when the difference is constant, the numbers are sequential.